# Vectorizing nested for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am studying a system of molecules consisting of atoms ("Sites" in the following code) and wish to construct the graph of just the molecules that are close to one another as defined by a distance criterion based on the atoms. The graph itself, though, is just supposed to show connections between the molecules as nodes.

How can I make this code more efficient? It is painfully slow. I imagine this isn't really a question about generating the graph, but about how to improve the nested for-loop structure of my code, plus the distance comparison given in matrix `B`.

I am working with MATLAB R2021b.

```
A % an array where column 1 is the atom ID, column 2 is the molecule ID, and columns 3-5 are the positions in x, y, and z
N = 200; % molecules in system
Sites = 150; % sites in each molecule
length = 120; % length of box on each side
SitesInSystem = N*Sites;
B = zeros(SitesInSystem,SitesInSystem);
for ii = 1:SitesInSystem
    for jj = 1:SitesInSystem
        
        if ii ~= jj % if not the same site
            
            dx = A(jj,3) - A(ii,3);
            dy = A(jj,4) - A(ii,4);
            dz = A(jj,5) - A(ii,5);
                
            % taking into account periodic boundaries
            if (dx >   length * 0.5)
                dx = dx - length;
            elseif (dx <= -length * 0.5) 
                dx = dx + length;
            end
            if (dy >   length * 0.5)
                dy = dy - length;
            elseif (dy <= -length * 0.5) 
                dy = dy + length;
            end
            if (dz >   length * 0.5)
                dz = dz - length;
            elseif (dz <= -length * 0.5) 
                dz = dz + length;
            end
                
            % calculate distances
            B(ii,jj) = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2);
                
        end

    end
end

B = triu(B); % to avoid double counting

for ii = 1:N % molecule
    for jj = 1:Sites % site
        for kk = 1:N
            for mm = 1:Sites

                if ii ~= kk % if not the same molecule

                    if (B(ii*jj,kk*mm) < 1.75) && (B(ii*jj,kk*mm) > 0)
                        % do a calculation, i.e., add edge ii-kk to a graph with N nodes
                    end
                        
                end

            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `if ii ~= kk` is independent of `mm`, so you could move it out of the inner loop. But the more efficient algorithm would loop only over the elements of `B` that satisfy the constraint. I don’t know what `B` is, but are you sure that `ii*jj` is the right way to index it? It makes no sense that you’d have the same value for molecule 5 and site 10, as for molecule 10 and site 5.

Comment: I agree, thanks. That's why I calculated `B` as an upper triangular matrix, but I did that via another cumbersome nested loop structure like this (could add this to my post if helpful). I hope there's a better / more efficient way.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I updated my post to include that issue about double counting, in case that's helpful.

Comment: So `A` has `N*Sites` rows? Hoe are they organized? Do you get `Sites` contiguous rows for each molecule? Or do you get `N` contiguous rows for each site? Or are they ordered randomly? This is important because in your bottom loops, where you index `B(ii*jj,kk*mm)`, you are reading the wrong values, no matter what this order is. You need to figure out how to properly index depending on the order of the rows in `A`. For example, if you have `Sites` contiguous rows for each molecule, you would index `A((ii-1)*Sites + jj)` (please check on paper why this is the case!).

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt `par for` to utilize all CPU cores in your machine.
Your first child loop (for jj = 1:SitesInSystem....) could be easily refactored to a par for.

P/s: Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I post this as an answer.